# Check if Listobject Filter Returns any results

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check whether a filtered listobject returns no results.

```
Public Function TestFilterResult() As Boolean
Dim filterArea As Range
Dim cellsCount As Long

Set filterArea = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range

cellsCount = filterArea.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

If cellsCount = 0 Then
    TestFilterResult = True
End If

End Function
```

However, the function incorrectly returns `TRUE` because it accounts for the header row which is always visible. Is there a way around this or perhaps a different approach altogether in checking this?

Comment: You're using Public Function so probably it would be UDF function. Notice, if you want to recalculate value of your UDF function you must use some workarounds. If you know your table name and it is static and you are sure every row contains data then you can use excel-built function subtotal "=SUBTOTAL(103,Table)=0" which will be better solution. Otherwise use BigBen's answer.

Comment: @RafałB. feel free to add that as a solution, SUBTOTAL is a good idea and you could easily translate that to VBA. If you add I will upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encouraged by BigBen's comment I would post another solution. If you're sure each of your table row always contains data you can use excel-built SUBTOTAL function

```
 Public Function TestFilterResult() As Boolean
   Dim tbl As ListObject
   Dim check As Boolean

   Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
   check = Application.Evaluate("SUBTOTAL(103," & tbl.Name & ")") = 0

     If check Then
       TestFilterResult = True
     End If

 End Function
```

But if your table is static better way will be to add column e.g. "Ordinal number" with function ROWS what will make you sure there are not empty rows in your table and then use "=SUBTOTAL(103,YourTableName)" just in Excel cell, there is no need using UDF and VBA in this case.

Comment: You could simplify to `TestFilterResult = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, tbl.DataBodyRange) = 0)` instead of using `Evaluate`, but yep.